# Could not reconnect all network drives

Tags: windows, windows-7

Each time I start Windows, I get a warning in my taskbar :

[image: network drives]
Is it possible to edit the list of network drives which have to be loaded at startup, so I can remove the missing one and get rid of this warning ?

When I click on Start Menu > Computer, I don't see any drive listed with a big red X.

Thanks

Comment: probably not possible because this is just triggered by a race condition. You could do all sorts of scripts but the warning would wrongfully appear either way, I'd assume. One workaround would be to map the drives "non persistent" meaning don't say "reconnect on start" in the gui. Then use a script to autoconnect at every login, thus taking control over the whole process and not letting windows decide. Only works well if you can connect to the drives without pwd (otherwise you would have to safe this in cleartext in the script). Also some programs rely on persistent mapping so tests are needed

Comment: http://talsit.info/2010/03/07/windows-7-disconnected-network-drives/

Comment: This may be a problem with delays in the establishment of the network, not uncommon if it's wireless. If you launch the Command Prompt `cmd` and type `dir x:`, replacing `x` with each of your network drives _before_ you start an `explorer` window, you will see which of you drives is not connected. If it's all of them, then you may need to live with the problem (I do), unless @magicandre1981's link works for you (the utility down-load link doesn't work for me).

Comment: @AFH try this link: http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/free-downloads?did=5

Comment: Afaik the problem this tool solves is only that if the network drives are not connected fast enough they will have a red cross, and will be only checked again if a user clicks them. This means even if they are available later if a PROGRAM tries to access them it fails. Only  windows explorer will trigger the check. However this is not what fop6316 really describes because he doesn't see the X. Imo for him the autoreconnect is just a tad too slow so the message triggers. As I said the best method to avoid this (if possible) is to replace the autoreconnect with a custom script

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Thanks for the link. Having looked at it, there don't seem to be many advantages over a batch file calling `net use ...` repeatedly, which can try several network drives in succession until they are all connected or a time / retry limit is reached, along the lines of the solution suggested by @Syberdoor.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies.
As you suggested, I think that the problem is due to the slowness of my computer.
My computer does not use a wireless connection, but it is so slow to boot that it must be the problem.
I can't use a program to automate the connections because those are made by my office policies.
I will live with this warning, don't worry :)